# Toggle-Animation only above certain window-width

Tags: jquery, resize, toggle, jsfiddle

I want to use a Toggle-Event, but only when the window is wider than a certain size. The DIV should be visible all the time though.
My solution kind of works, but the if-statement doesn't trigger anymore, once I resize the window.

Any hints?
Here's the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/mihaene/wMrjc/

Comment: yeah so I think I have a solution but I am not quite sure if I get the problem correctly. So I rephrase it first: you want to have that box displayed in each window size, you want to have the toggle only at widths > 500 else you do not want the toggle. Is that correct?

Comment: exactly, sorry for my misleading explantation.

Comment: You put a comma in the wrong place, which changes the context of the entire question. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, assuming that I have figured out your problem I just post my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/5bxLS/

```
var toggleOn = false;
var toggleState = 0;
function slideIn() {
     toggleState = 1;
     $("#slider").stop().animate({bottom: "-20px"}, 300);
};
function slideOut() {
    toggleState = 0;
    $("#slider").stop().animate({bottom: "-180px"}, 300) ;
};
function setToggle() {
    if(!toggleOn) {
        $('#slider').toggle(slideIn, slideOut);
        toggleOn = true;
    }
};
function clearToggle() {
    if(toggleOn) {
        if(toggleState === 1)
            $('#slider').click();        
        $('#slider').off('click');   
        toggleOn = false;
    }
};
function evalToggle() {
    if ($(window).width() > 500)
        setToggle();
    else
        clearToggle();
};
    //Apparently this does not work in webkit based browsers...
/*$(window).resize(evalToggle);
evalToggle();*/
    //But this works:
    $(window).resize(evalToggle).resize();
```

In order to stop the toggling you will have to unbind the event (which is click event in this case). The click event is also the one that executes the toggling. I build my solution in a way that toggling can be enabled in the beginning (depending on the window size).
Additionally I've made a smooth transition if the toggle state was set to on if the window is made smaller.
Hope this was the one you were searching for!

Comment: Hey Florian! Thanks a lot. I get the idea, don't understand it to the detail, but it works perfectly. I just don't fully understand, why in my solution the if-statement didn't trigger anymore, once you resize the window. Anyway: Good job!

Comment: Sorry, me again. I copy pasted your code and tried it in a website. There it doesnt work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong: "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" at "evalToggle()".
Shouldn't there be brackets at the if/else statement? I tried with brackets, but still error.

Comment: Everything with the brackets is fine (if its just a single statement you can omit those brackets). In order to know what breaks at your page I need the source or a link to the source. If you provide it here (or write me a message) I will have a short look at it!

Comment: Hm works perfect for me - which browser are you using? I am using Opera 11.62

Comment: Yes - really strange. I do have to say I do not know what webkit's problem is with that, however, if you just replace the last two lines with the following line: $(window).resize(evalToggle).resize(); - you will have no problems.

Comment: Hey! Cool, thanks. 
It first didn't work again. Then I made complete new file. There, it worked. Then I tried the old file again, and suddenly it worked. It's a mistery… Maybe some problems with the cache? Anyway: Thanks.