# Div slides in after scrolling down

Tags: jquery, scroll, slide, scrolltop

Here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/mihaene/7bdkB/

I want a div to slide in, as soon as I scroll down a certain amount of pixel.
It works, but very, very delayed (like 5seconds).
What's the problem?

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I think the problem is your else block. jQuery is then starting the animation which takes ~300 ms.

```
var $test2 = $(".test2");
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $test2.stop().animate({left: "200px"}, 300);
    } else {
        $test2.stop().animate({left: "-90px"}, 300);
    }
});
```

So just use the stop() method of jQuery to stop those animations.

On a sidenote: maybe you should think of different if / else statements in order not to get an animation (or stop / restart) with every scrolling event as other suggested.

Comment: I can't think of a different if/else statement for that case though… do you think it's bad for performance to use it that way?

Comment: And… Do you happen to have an answer to this case:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514554/toggle-animation-only-above-certain-window-width

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution I can think of, do correct me if I'm wrong.

The events are stacked and get fired one after the other. So my solution is to hold them in a queue and clear the queue whenever required.

I used [queue](http://jqapi.com/#p=queue)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/KdTct/)**

Hope this helps

Comment: I prefer to put the function on a timer and fire after scrolling stops for a short period of time.  Like 250ms.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Works pretty good. I don't entirely get it with the queuing, but nice!!

Answer (score 0):

Your jsfiddle example doesn't have a delay issue, but that's probably because the window size is small and there aren't many opportunities for scroll to fire.  The possible cause for the delay is the frequency of the scroll function firing.  They can get stacked up quickly and cause the delay.

Add a console.log (if using Firebug) and see the frequency in the console to get a better understanding of the frequency.

Comment: I tried this, and it fires very fast. Nevertheless, the animation starts very delayed: 
$(document).scroll(function() {
    console.log($(document).scrollTop());
})

Comment: Does it react fast, when you look at it?